# 18.04 wifi connection stopped - it works on USB stick bootup

Tags: networking, 18.04

no install, no download, just during a webpage viewing the wifi stopped working. A safe site with no viruses - verified a safe site.

- Wifi works on other devices.
- Wifi works on this same 18.04 machine(when/now booted on usb stick)
- I get a question mark icon instead of the
  connection icon on a regular bootup
- Now on the usb stick I get the connection icon and it works.
- The network settings have not changed and appear correct and working
- have rebooted, unplugged, and reset network connections and modem many times.

any help appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver issue and I suspect it is corrupted on your hard drive since it is working fine on your thumb drive.
Before you trying the following suggestions, restart your machine and if it still doesn't load then try the following.

Run `sudo lspci` to see if the wifi card is being detected. You should see something like Wifi listed in your output. If none then the card is not being detected.
If you see it, now run `sudo lsmod`. This will list all your loaded modules. It can be too much output so you might wana filter the output with grep but you need to know the exact name of your wireless chipset. If you do not find anything in the output, then your wireless module is clearly not loading. You can manualy reload it with: `sudo modprobe name_of_your_wireless_chip` and rerun `sudo lsmod` to see if it has loaded.
If this doesn't help, try re installing the OS. Driver issues can be cumbersome if you are not very experienced with the linux terminal.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I am having a difficult time determining "what is the wireless chip name" - My mother board is a z370-g but when I research the name I dont get any information that says wireless chipset name. Is there are master list of some kind that determins a wireless chipset name?

Comment: Also I am having to use your second part of the instructions using sudo modprobe because there was "none" on sudo 1spci command

Comment: My last update solved this problem automatically - or for some unknown reason it fixed itself - it just started working again and have not had any more issues with it.